# Difference between stereo camera calibration vs two single camera calibrations using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I have a vehicle with two cameras, left and right. Is there a difference between me calibrating each camera separately vs me performing "stereo calibration" ? I am asking because I noticed in the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5) that there is a stereoCalibrate function, and also a stereo calibration tool for MATLAB. If I do separate camera calibration on each and then perform a depth calculation using the undistorted images of each camera, will the results be the same ?

I am not sure what the difference is between the two methods. I performed normal camera calibration for each camera separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
You need stereo calibration if you want 3D points.

**Long answer**
There is a huge difference between single and stereo camera calibration.

The output of single camera calibration are intrinsic parameters only (i.e. the 3x3 camera matrix and a number of distortion coefficients, depending on the model used). In OpenCV this is accomplished by `cv2.calibrateCamera`. You may check [my custom library](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/master/examples/003%20BuildStereoRig.py) that helps reducing the boilerplate.

When you do stereo calibration, its output is given by the intrinsics of both cameras **and** the extrinsic parameters.
In OpenCV this is done with `cv2.stereoCalibrate`. OpenCV fixes the world origin in the first camera and then you get a rotation matrix `R` and translation vector `t` to go from the first camera (origin) to the second one.

So, *why do we need extrinsics?* If you are using a stereo system for 3D scanning then you need those (and the intrinsics) to do *triangulation*, so to obtain 3D points in the space: if you know the projection of a general point `p` in the space on both cameras, then you can calculate its position.

To add something to what @Christoph correctly answered before, the intrinsics *should* be *almost* the same, however, `cv2.stereoCalibrate` may improve the calculation of the intrinsics if the flag `CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` is not set. This happens because the system composed by two cameras and the calibration board is solved as a whole by numerical optimization.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to simply use photos taken by the two cameras of the same known geometry (e.g. checkerboard) and call `cv.calibrateCamera`? Won't this result in valid `R` and `t` vectors?

Comment: The output of `cv.calibrateCamera` doesn't provide the extrinsic parameter, only the intrinsic ones (one camera at a time). The returned `rvecs` and `tvecs` are not the extrinsic parameters you are looking for (they are the transformation from camera center to chessboard center).
You need `cv2.stereoCalibrate` for stereo calibration.

Comment: I thought not setting CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC would make it drift alot can you elaborate more on how not setting it is a good idea ? 
do you mean to calibrate cameras individually first then letting stereoCalibrate optimize it further ?

Comment: No. I mean that if you use `cv.calibrateCamera` you are calibrating a single camera, thus extrinsics do not apply as you are considering one camera at a time. You need extrinsics when calibrating two (or more) cameras *together* as a system. In the case of two cameras you would use `cv.stereoCalibrate`. It can find the intrinsic matrix of each camera for you (it does without any issue), but if you already have them, you may set `CALIB_FIX_INTRISIC` to speed up the optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

For *intrinsics*, it doesn't matter. The added information ("pair of cameras") might make the calibration a little better though.

Stereo calibration gives you the **extrinsics**, i.e. transformation matrices between cameras. That's for... *stereo vision*. If you don't perform stereo calibration, you would lack the extrinsics, and then you can't do any depth estimation at all, because that requires the extrinsics.

Comment: Actually you don't need to do stereo calibration, just need to have at least one image acquired with both cameras and evaluate the extrinsic. But the errors will probably be higher.

Comment: Actually you *do*, if you want to do depth estimation. Either do calibration or your problem becomes SFM, which is a lot harder than just depth from stereo.